# Same Global Entry membership/PASSID number for husband and wife?

Tags: global-entry

My wife and I just finished our Global Entry interviews today, and we both already got the notifications that we're approved. I just logged into each account in order to copy the PASSID number so I can fill it in for tickets we already have booked.

I noticed our Membership/PASSID numbers are the same. This is the number shown on https://ttp.cbp.dhs.gov/dashboard as well as the generated letter under "Approval Notifications" is this expected?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would [call](https://help.cbp.gov/s/article/Article-ContactUs?language=en_US) the CBP, this doesn't seem right.

Let's look at https://www.tsa.gov/travel/frequently-asked-questions/what-are-cbp-passid-and-known-traveler-number-0

> Your PASSID is your Known Traveler Number

> you must add your PASSID number in the KTN field when making airline reservations to ensure the TSA PreCheck® indicator appears on your boarding pass.

And https://www.cbp.gov/travel/trusted-traveler-programs/global-entry/frequently-asked-questions

> Do my Global Entry benefits extend to my travel companion(s) (children, spouse or co-traveler) who is/are not part of the Global Entry program?

> Global Entry benefits are member specific and cannot be extended to others.

So this just doesn't mesh together. If your PASSID were the same it would extend benefits to each other. Call the CBP -- but make sure you read those numbers right.

Secondary source: https://slate.com/human-interest/2020/01/tsa-precheck-couples-divide.html it does happen that only one half of a  couple has TSA Pre.

Comment: I agree. My wife and I went through the process a few years ago, and were issued different numbers. I think a same-number response is an error.

Comment: Same here. My partner and I have different IDs

Comment: Thanks to the answerer and the commenters. I sent a message thru the "contact us" form at CBP GE website. I attached the PDF versions of our approval notifications.

Comment: It is not correct that you have the same number. It could, however, be that this comes from a poor website design - you log out A and then log on B, but parts of the website looks into the old cookies and uses A's data.
Try on another device, or in 'incognito' mode to verify.

Comment: @Aganju looking at the comment above you that looks unlikely, OP seems to have these numbers cooked into PDFs.